# Redhat trying to use pip ImportError: No module named pip

Tags: python, pip, redhat

I am trying to use pip on my Redhat system.

I installed pip following the instructions [here](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html), but when I try to use it, for example `pip install`, I get the following error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in ?
    from pip import main
ImportError: No module named pip
```

Comment: have you use `sudo yum install python-pip` and got success message ?

Answer (score 1):

this issue due to common user do not have privilege to access packages py file.
1. root user can run 'pip list'
2. other common user cannot run 'pip list'

```
[~]$ pip list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
ImportError: No module named pip._internal
```

solution :
root user login and run

```
chmod -R 755 /usr/lib/python2.7
```

fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If pip is already installed and your unable to access it, one of the reason could be that you don't have permissions to read or execute the library. Try doing

```
sudo chmod -R u+rx /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/
```

If pip is installed in a different folder, you can obtain the folder path by doing

```
>>> import pip
>>> pip.__path__
['/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have root rights and running on python 2.6 then you can try this file https://bootstrap.pypa.io/2.6/get-pip.py (it is from same instruction you used, it is a simple python script which installs all dependencies and pip itself) and run it with command `python get-pip.py --user`

Comment: Add a description about the link.